# Symfony hangs after using Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I am trying to debug something so I made this test controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test")
 */
public function reventarAction()
{
    $a = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(MyTable::class)
        ->find(1);

    var_dump($a->getId());
    die();
}
```

This works just fine. The ID gets dumped.

However, when I try to debug something else such as the object itself:

```
var_dump($a);
```

It loads forever presumably in some sort of recursive loop to the point where my computer freezes.

Any help debugging from Doctrine?

Comment: What's happening is normal when you try to dump an entity. Firstly, don't dump object just like that. Dump whatever you need. Secondly, use [The VarDumper Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html).

Comment: In dev mode, you can use `dump($entity)` instead of var_dump

Comment: tbh, I hanged my server so many times, because I typed var_dump instead of dump (old habits). So I feel your pain. And yes, it's most likely because of infinite recursion ... and it stinks.